# How to pass enum in Sprinboot backend using api call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, enums

I'm totally new to java spring boot and I'm trying to study and develop an application in the same time.What I need to do here is get enums in the backend to UI as api call. I can't think of a way how to do this.Can you give me an idea how to pass them hrough an api call?

**TicketStatusVO.java**

```
package limark.internal.css.api.v1.model.enums;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public enum TicketStatusVO {
    UNASSIGNED,
    ASSIGNED,
    IN_PROGRESS,
    BLOCKED,
    RESERVED,
    ARCHIVED;
}
```

**Resource.java**

```
 /**
   * API to get all enums
   * @return list of enums
   */
  @GetMapping("/getEnums")
  public TicketStatusVO getEnums() {

//TODO
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Return an array and do `return TicketStatusVO.values()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @m-deinum said you can return Array of TicketStatusVO.

```
  public enum TicketStatusVO {
    UNASSIGNED,
    ASSIGNED,
    IN_PROGRESS,
    BLOCKED,
    RESERVED,
    ARCHIVED;
  }

  @GetMapping("/getEnums")
  public TicketStatusVO[] getEnums() {
    return TicketStatusVO.values();
  }
```

Also, you should define the URLs for Rest API with some good names that justify the returning values. For example :

```
  @GetMapping("/ticketStatus")
  public TicketStatusVO[] getTicketStatus() {
    return TicketStatusVO.values();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
@GetMapping("/getEnums")
public TicketStatusVO[] getEnums() {
   return TicketStatusVO.values();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@GetMapping("/getEnums")
public TicketStatusVO[] getEnums() {
    return TicketStatusVO.values();
}
```

Try this above with array or convert to a list as presented below

```
@GetMapping("/getEnums")
public List<TicketStatusVO> getEnums() {
    return Arrays.asList(TicketStatusVO.values());
}
```